# How to run jpos inside a docker container?

Tags: java, docker, iso, jpos

**I want to run jpos (isoserver) within a docker container**. So far I have found [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/jpos/ubuntu_vivid_jdk8/) image in Docker hub. I didn't able to found any **details documentation about this image**. Only few lines are available in **readme**.

I have found few Docker files and build was successful.But when I try to run , it takes me to a bash prompt.I have run this command

> docker run -t -i jpos/ubuntu_trusty_jdk8 /bin/bash

**No q2 server is running.** **No Logs are available** in docker container when i try to run this command.

> sudo docker logs 7c2661e82141

Can I use existing docker image for my requirements? If yes ,where are the details documentation for **how to run, modify existing docker image**?

Can anybody help?

[Github link](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS)

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at the [Docker files](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/tree/master/dockerfiles).

If you use the [jPOS-template](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS-template), you can create a Dockerfile of your own, like this:

```
FROM jpos/ubuntu_jdk8:latest

ADD jpos/build/distributions/jpos*.tar.gz /
LABEL vendor="jPOS.org"
LABEL org.jpos.template="2.1.1 master/2a2874f"
RUN ln -s /jpos-2.1.1 /jpos
WORKDIR /jpos

CMD ["bin/q2"]
```

Then you can build your image with a script like this:

```
!/bin/bash

cd `dirname $0`
rm -fr jpos 
git clone https://github.com/jpos/jPOS-template.git jpos
(cd jpos && gradle dist)
docker rmi jpos/template
docker build -t="jpos/yourproject" .
```

(You obviously clone from your project, based on jPOS-template).

Key points here:

- `gradle dist` creates a distribution in `build/distributions` directory
- `ADD jpos/build/distributions/jpos*.tar.gz /` in the Dockerfile expands the tarball inside your container.

Answer (score 0):

As the Dockerfile of the image, you are referring to uses:
CMD ["bash"] which means it will execute bash.

You can create your own image using Dockerfile where the base image would be jpos/ubuntu_vivid_jdk8 and you can specify the default command using ENTRYPOINT or CMD.
Please refer https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

Please let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. There are lots of example available with Spring boot and docker. I have gone through few of them. But problem is , jpos is a modular gradle project. I am not getting any clue to start. Few example will be very helpful.Thanks